# Header and Footer div are fixed and scrollbar for middel div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add scroll bar to my div, with fixed header and footer.

My code is,

```
<div id="header" class="form-group form-group-sm"></div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="container"></div>
```

CSS is,

```
.col-xs-6{    
        float:left;
        width :50%;
}
.main{
    float:left;
    width :100%;
    background-color: skyblue;
    overflow: auto;
}
#header,#footer{
     float:left; 
     width :100%;
}
```

I have used overflow tag but, it is not working properly.

Comment: where you want scroll?

Comment: Edit your question to fix the HTML markup...its invalid..

Comment: There is no class to first class to first div

Comment: @Rupal for manl div.

Comment: just add max-height  and then use overflow:scroll

Comment: your html is totally messed up you need to first fix your html and then work on the css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some max-height or height and then use overflow:scroll to work. Also use some row and container before using col-sm type classes. And never use css on col-sm-6. because it will destroy default functionality. Use code like:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
   
</head>
<body>
 <style type="text/css">
  .text{

            float:left;
            width :50%;
        }
        .main{

            float:left;
            width :100%;
            background-color: skyblue;
            overflow: scroll;
       max-height: 200px;
        }
        #header,#footer{
             float:left; 
             width :100%;

        }
 </style>
 <div id=header class=form-group form-group-sm>
</div>
 <div class=" container-fluid main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text">
     What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text">
     What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


    </div>
</div>
  </div>
<div id=footer class=container>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add your content which is more then .main div height then it will be scrollable

**DEMO:**

```css
.ax{
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    width :400px;
}
.main{
    max-height:100px;
    float:left;
    width :100%;
    background-color: skyblue;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#header,#footer{
     float:left; 
     width :100%;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id=header class=form-group form-group-sm>
    </div>
     <div class="main">
     wkjkjnkrnf
     <div class="ax">
     </div>
     <div class="ax">
     </div>
      </div>
    <div id=footer class=container>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may help you:

```
<header>
       //header content
</header>
<main style="overflow-y:auto">
      //main content
</main>
<footer>
      //footer content
</footer>
```